# Error With doctrine/commons 1.2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I use Symfony 2.3 and I have problems with doctrine/commons 1.2

this is my code

```
$criteria = Criteria::create()
    ->orderBy(array("createdAt" => Criteria::DESC,'id' => Criteria::DESC))
;
return $this->my_array_collection->matching($criteria);
```

in doctrine/commons 1.1 It's works

In doctrine/commons 1.2 dosen't works...
The error is

Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right...

***Update***

```
Entity/Profile.php
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="..\Entity\NotifyBase", mappedBy="dest")
     */
    protected $my_array_collection;


Entity/NotifyBase


...
/**
 * NotifyBase
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="my_table")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *          "s"                        = "..\Entity\notifyS",
 *          "d"                        = "..\Entity\notifyD",
 *          "r"                        = "..\Entity\notifyR",
 *          "p"                        = "..\Entity\notifyP",
 * })
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="..\Entity\NotifyBaseRepository")
 */
class NotifyBase
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="..\Entity\Profile", inversedBy="my_array_collection")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="dest_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $dest;
```

Comment: This is rather incomplete question. We have no clue what that `my_array_collection` contains. Also, error-wise, this is just the beginning of error message. Please add some more info.

Comment: Thanks @jperovic. I've add more code